# How to read a variable in json file when accessing that json file from a batch file

Tags: json, shell, batch-file, command-line, forgerock

I have batch test.bat where I have set variables and I want access those variables in json file.

```
           json file 
    {

    "jdbcUrl" : "jdbc:postgresql://&{openidm.repo.host}:&{openidm.repo.port}/& 
           {test.rds.dbname}"
      }
```

batch file looks like

```
          set hostname="abc.host"
         -Dopenidm.repo.host=%hostname%
```

&{openidm.repo.host} is working fine in shell script can you pls suggest instead of & what I need to use for my bat file
for bat file is is somethinh like this %{openidm.repo.host}?????

Comment: you want to read a value from a json file or you want to replace the values in a json file?

Comment: I want replace values in json file